# Define a private variable in a header file or cpp file without using class?

Tags: c++, variables, private

Hi I have a question that, without using class, is there any other way to define a 'private' variable which can only be seen inside of a module, so that when we include different modules into a file, those variables with same name in different modules don't conflict ?

I know the simplest way to solve this is to have different names, but I am actually translating fortran code to C++, and I don't really want to change the name unless I have to.

The reason I don't want to use a class is that, it is really a large module, with many, many variables. It would be weird to me to have so many private variables inside of a class.

Thank you very much!

I think variables inside of header file will be public anyway, because when you include a header file into another file, you literally copy everything to the later file. Based on this idea I tried moving those 'should-be-private' varialbes from header file to it's corresponding cpp file. But still doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Putting the variable in the CPP file is the canonical way to make a global variable private. to that TU.  Can we get a code example of what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, have a look at c `static` or anonymous struct to hide these.

Comment: @NathanOliver just that won't hide it from the linker

Comment: If you open your advanced C++ textbook to the chapter that explains anonymous namespaces, you will find a complete explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can also put the variable in an anonymous (unnamed) namespace.  Every compilation unit (which means, roughly, every source `.cpp` file) can have its own anonymous namespace which defines variables that cannot be seen by other compilation units.

Comment: C++ modules are in their infancy. They are still finicky and cannot be recommended to beginners. It is better to ignore them completely. Stick with good old header files.

Comment: Global states (variables) are main source of evil code. Just avoid global variables.

Comment: I suspect where OP is saying "module" they don't actually mean C++ modules and instead mean "translation-unit".

Comment: @MooingDuck yeah, to most languages (translation-)unit translates as "module" in this context

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

###### Use a named namespace in a header file

Suppose `module1.h` and `module2.h` contain the names from two Fortran modules.

If those headers are both included in the same `.cpp` file, then any duplicate names will cause *duplicate definition* errors at compile time.

A simple workaround is to place those names within a *named namespace*.

In the header files, each name should be declared `extern`. This tells the compiler that a declaration is not a *defining declaration*. Those will be placed in `.cpp` files.

```cpp
// module1.h
#ifndef module1_H
#define module1_H
namespace mod1
{
    extern double x, y, z;
    extern int n;
}
#endif
```

```cpp
// module2.h
#ifndef module2_H
#define module2_H
namespace mod2
{
    extern double a, b, c;
    extern int n;
}
#endif
```

You also need to define each name in its `.cpp` file. In this case, you might have `module1.cpp` and `module2.cpp`.

The definitions in the `.cpp` files cause storage to be allocated for the names that were previously declared `extern` in the header files.

```cpp
// module1.cpp
namespace mod1
{
    double x, y, z;
    int n;
}
```

```cpp
// module2.cpp
namespace mod2
{
    double a, b, c;
    int n;
}
```

When one of these headers is included in a `.cpp` file, you have to use the *scope resolution operator* (::), together with the name of the namespace, to reference its variables.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "module1.h"
#include "module2.h"
int main()
{
    mod1::n = 0;
    mod2::n = 1;
    mod2::a = 3.14;
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

###### Use an anonymous namespace in a `.cpp` file

If the names you need can be placed in separate `.cpp` files, and do not need to appear in a header file, then you can dispense with the named namespaces. Instead, the names should be placed within an *anonyomous namespace* in the `.cpp` file.

Names defined within an anonymous namespace are not exported to the linker. They have *static linkage*, and can only be used in the translation unit where they first appear. This is probably the best approximation to the "private" variables mentioned in the OP.

```cpp
// module3.cpp
namespace 
{
    double x, y, z;
    int n;
}
void funcA()
{
    x = 3.14;
    n = 0;
    // ...
}
```

```cpp
// module4.cpp
namespace 
{
    double a, b, c;
    int n;
}
void funcB()
{
    a = 2.7;
    n = 1;
    // ...
}
```

###### Using modules from C++20

C++20 modules might be the best way of all for dealing with this. The names defined in a module are not exported unless you explicitly designate that they should be. Therefore, you can import multiple modules into the same translation unit (i.e., "file") without worrying about name collisions.

Modules are still relatively new, however, and can be finicky. That's why I am not posting an example that uses them.